# Nuxt Buefy components using CDN

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, buefy

I am new to nuxt. I want to know whether is it possible to use Buefy on nuxt just by using CDN 
as I directly imported beufy CDN in script in head function of nuxt.config
But it gave error while using navbar of beufy that the component is not registered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt supports buefy by default, when installing using **npx create-nuxt-app** you'll be asked if you want to use a component framework (buefy is an option here).

If you want to use it in an installed project you can **npm install buefy --save** and then add "nuxt-buefy" in the modules array of your nuxt.config